# Calling for ViewModel variables dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wonder if there is any way to call for variables in a ViewModel by another variable declared in the foreach I've printed below.

This is written in c# (Razor file).

Working example, but only looks in table "Users" and field "Password":

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tables.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date))
{
  @Model.Users.Where(r=>r.ID == item.TableRow_ID).FirstOrDefault().Password
}
```

What I want:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tables.OrderByDescending(r => r.Date))
{
   @Model.**item.TableName**.Where(r=>r.ID ==
   (item.TableRow_ID)).FirstOrDefault().**item.Field**
}
```

Is this possible in anyway? Or should I look for another fix to my problem?

Update: Avoiding the XY-problem

I have an audit trail that is storing the old value of an edit. I want to show the "new value" too, but storing it in the trail would be redundant since it is stored as the new value of the field that got edited. 
So I want to use the values I already got in the Audit trail, which is stored in item (table name, row id and field name), to get the "new value" directly from the table containing the "new value".

So in the code i posted, the working example is how I get the "new value" by entering the name of the table and field (Users and Password). But that won't work if i want the field "Username".
And since I got too many table names and fields to make if/switch, I wonder how I can achieve a solution to get the "new value" with table name, row id and field name.

Comment: You need to use reflection.But why did you want to dynamically?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - You should ask what you really want instead of what you *think* might work.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about what I want.
I want to dynamically get data, based on table name and table field. 
I could for example make if-statements for each table and each field, but I'd prefer if it would work with a dynamic solution, since its around 20 tables and each table got multiple fields.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: I updated the question. Is reflection/dictionary still the way to go?